# Use pom as a maven system scope dependency

Tags: maven, maven-2, dependency-management

Is it possible to use a pom file as a maven system scoped dependency and resolve its transitive dependencies as well?

Comment: May be you can give more details what you like to achieve so it will be simpler to give a wise advise.

Comment: It is actually pretty simple to verify by just trying to do so. Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use system-scoped dependencies, cause it will make your build non transferable to other system. Furthermore it sounds you like to do a import like usage of the pom file which can be achieved by the import scope. Details can be found in [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using local repositories. Set this in your POM:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-project-repo</id>
        <url>file:${basedir}/lib/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then recreate a Maven repository layout under /lib/repository. You could place here a POM artifact and transitive dependencies will be resolved.

Of course, you will need to ship the dependencies (inside the local repo) with your project.